# iText PDF Forms: How do you change the tooltip for a field?

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I'm using the iText library which is baked into ColdFusion to rename PDF form fields.  I can rename the field name easy enough, however the resulting PDF shows a "tooltip" when you hover your mouse over the field which does not match the new name of the field.

I did some research and it looks like the tooltip is stored in the "/TU" key in the field dictionary and it can be set with the `setUserName()` method.  However, when I examine the various objects in my code, I don't see any way to gain access to that method for a particular PDF field.

How can I set this "/TU" key using the iText library?

Here's my code so far:

```
 function renameFields( pathToFile ) {

    // initialize the PDF file we will be working on
    local.pdfService = new pdf();
    local.pdfService.setSource( arguments.pathToFile );
    local.pdfFile = local.pdfService.read();

    // initialize the iText library objects
    local.pdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( toBinary( local.pdfFile ) );
    local.outputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    local.pdfStamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( local.pdfReader, local.outputStream);

    // get an instance of the acro fields object
    local.acroFields = local.pdfStamper.getAcroFields();

    // Get All of the Fields of the PDF
    local.allFields = local.acroFields.getFields();

    // convert the collection of fields into an array for easy iteration
    local.fieldArray = listToArray( structKeyList( local.acroFields.getFields() ) );

    // loop through all fields and rename them
    for ( var a=1; a < arrayLen( local.fieldArray ); a++ ) {

         // do the actual renaming
         local.acroFields.renameField( local.fieldArray[a], "field_#a#" );

         // update the field tooltip ???

    }

    // finish up and return the pdf file object
    local.pdfStamper.setFormFlattening( false );
    local.pdfStamper.close();
    local.pdfReader.close();
    local.myPdf = local.outputStream.toByteArray();

    return local.myPdf;

}
```

**CFML Solution** (update 7/31/2018)

*Note: In this solution I change the tooltip first and then rename the field.*

```
function renameFields( pathToFile ) {

    // initialize the PDF file we will be working on
    local.pdfService = new pdf();
    local.pdfService.setSource( arguments.pathToFile );
    local.pdfFile = local.pdfService.read();

    // initialize the iText library objects
    local.pdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( toBinary( local.pdfFile ) );
    local.outputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    local.pdfStamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( local.pdfReader, local.outputStream);

    // get an instance of the acro fields object
    local.acroFields = local.pdfStamper.getAcroFields();

    // Get All of the Fields of the PDF
    local.allFields = local.acroFields.getFields();

    // convert the collection of fields into an array for easy iteration
    local.fieldArray = listToArray( structKeyList( local.acroFields.getFields() ) );

    // loop through all fields and rename them
    for ( var a=1; a < arrayLen( local.fieldArray ); a++ ) {

        // create the tooltip text
        local.newTooltip = createObject( "java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfString" ).init( "field_#a#" );

        // update the field tooltip
        local.field = local.acroFields.getFieldItem( local.fieldArray[a] );
        local.field.values[ 1 ].put( local.pdfName.TU, local.newTooltip );

        // do the actual renaming
        local.acroFields.renameField( local.fieldArray[a], "field_#a#" );

    }

    // finish up and return the pdf file object
    local.pdfStamper.setFormFlattening( false );
    local.pdfStamper.close();
    local.pdfReader.close();
    local.myPdf = local.outputStream.toByteArray();

    return local.myPdf;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know ColdFusion (syntax) but the solution should look something like this:

```
// loop through all fields and rename them
for ( var a=1; a < arrayLen( local.fieldArray ); a++ ) {

     // do the actual renaming
     local.acroFields.renameField( local.fieldArray[a], "field_#a#" );

     // update the field tooltip (if you already renamed it might have to use the new name)
     Item field = local.acroFields.getFieldItem(local.fieldArray[a]);
     field.getValue(0).put(PdfName.TU, new PdfString("SomeNewTooltip"));
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I had to tweak your solution a bit to work with CFML but ultimately it lead me to the right answer.  See my original question for the working code. Thank you very much!